# Counter php-js doesn't update in the database

Tags: php, javascript

I made a counter that counts from one to infinity and if I refresh the page it doesn't stop.
However I have used ajax to update some datas in the database and this isn't working well ...
I think the problem is  thet the ajax file dosn't run

**HTML :**

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createXMLHttpRequest(){
    var ua;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        try {
            ua = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }catch(e) {
            ua = false;
        }
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        try{
            ua = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch(e) {
            ua = false;
        }}
return ua;}
var some = createXMLHttpRequest(c);
function some1(){
    some.open('GET', 'Untitled_4.php?value='+c);
    some.onreadystatechange = hand;
}
function hand() {
 if(some.readyState == 4) 
 {      
       some.send(null);
 }
}
var c=
<?php 

    $c= mysql_fetch_array( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `clock` WHERE `id`=1"));
    $l=time()-$c['time'];
    $a=$l/1;
    $a=floor($a);
    $a=$a+$c['value'];
    echo $a;

?>;
var t;
var timer_is_on=0;

function timedCount()
{
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=c;
c=c+1;
t=setTimeout("timedCount()",1000);
}

function doTimer()
{
if (!timer_is_on)
  {
  timer_is_on=1;
  timedCount();
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body onunload="some1(c)" onload="doTimer()">
<form>
<div  id="txt" ></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**AJAX File :**

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$value=$_GET['value'];
mysql_query("UPDATE `clock` SET `time`=".time().",`value`= $value  WHERE `id` = 1 ");
echo "1";
?>
```

Comment: Hi @asafg8, it will be easier to help you if you provide more information about what 'isn't working well'.  What is the behaviour you are expecting?  What is actually happening?  What errors are you getting? etc.

Comment: It does not run the ajax file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readystate` won't update unless you send the `XMLHttpRequest`.
The following version of `some1` should fix your problem:

```
function some1(){
    some.open('GET', 'Untitled_4.php?value='+c);
    some.send(null);
}
```

You don't really need the `onreadystatechanged` handler because you send the request when the page unloads and there won't be enough time to handle a change of the XMLHttpRequest's state I guess.